# Stacking reviews - Project to create a health virtual assistant using Dialogflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am working on a project to create an online medical booking system using Dialogflow as the frontend to provide users with a more personable experience.

So far I have come up with an ideal stack [PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdbwF.png). I plan to have it hosted on AWS (or GCP). However, I am new to Dialogflow but I know it is a very powerful platform. My two criteria are: (A) A stack that makes it easy to personalize frontend UI display and (B) Scalability, I am starting with a web app but would like to also develop an iOS app.

**I have two questions:** (1) Would you change anything in the stack? and (2) Is there a way to change the name of the bot each time user visits (to make it more "real")?

Super appreciative of you guys expert opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I've found GCP to be easier to use than AWS, since Google handles SSL encryption with .app domains, while AWS requires a more manual solution. Google Cloud also offers a terminal window inside a Chrome tab, which can be a fun experience. So, for hosting, I recommend Google Cloud, unless AWS has a unique feature that applies to your personal circumstances.

Personally, I prefer Angular to React, but Angular, React, and VueJS are all fine choices for a front-end framework on a web app. Your choice of these probably depends on which framework you already know, or (if you plan to outsource development) which language you can use to hire better engineering talent.

For my own projects, I use Express and Node on the server side, instead of GraphQL and Prisma. Your call there.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Max, I wonder what are your thoughts on NodeJS vs GraphQL and Prisma?

Comment: @Khang - I haven't heard much before about GraphQL or Prisma, but if you're comparing them against NodeJS, I like Node for a few reasons:
- There are a lot of client libraries built for NodeJS, meaning a lot of larger software companies have worked hard to make sure their products integrate well with Node. For example, the developer platform for Google Assistant allows third party devs to build a Google Assistant action in Node, but I haven't seen docs for GraphQL or Prisma.
- Node packages are easy to add to a web app, so you can pull in prebuilt functions and avoid reinventing the wheel.